# sql query to print id and sales from Table A for rows where sales of current year is greater than last year?

Tags: sql

I want to do the following using SQL:

> A query to print id and sales from Table a for rows where sales of current year is greater than last year

Let's take the following input for example:

```
id,sales,year
1,20k,1991
1,21k,1992
2,30k,1992
2,20k,1993
```

Added create table statement for reference.

```
CREATE TABLE a(id INT, sales INT, year INT);
INSERT INTO a VALUES(1, 20000, 1991);
INSERT INTO a VALUES(1, 21000, 1992);
INSERT INTO a VALUES(2, 30000, 1992);
INSERT INTO a VALUES(2, 20000, 1993);
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What if a year is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `lag()` . . . twice:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             lag(year) over (partition by id) as prev_year,
             lag(sales) over (partition by id) as prev_sales
      from a
     ) a
where prev_year = year - 1 and sales > prev_sales;
```

You need both lags to handle the case where years might be missing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with something like this you can get what you want, using pure sql (valid for all rdbms's)

```
select
  b.id, b.sales, b.year
from TableA a
  join TableA b
    on a.id = b.id
   and a.year = b.year-1
where a.sales < b.sales
```